# How to copy file from one location to another on production server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-io

I want to copy one file from another location and I made code for that and it works fine on local but issue comes on production.Every time I am getting error as below.

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\Websites\test\test.xyz.com\App_Data\GeoIP2-Country.mmdb' because
>   it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at
>   Nop.Services.Directory.UpdateMaxMindDatabaseTask.UpdateLocalMaxMindDb()
>   at Nop.Services.Directory.UpdateMaxMindDatabaseTask.Execute(XmlNode
>   node),,IP=,CustomerId=unknown,Page=,Referrer=

My code to copy the file is as below.

```
try
{
 if (File.Exists(localDbPath))
                        {
                            var lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(localDbPath);
                            if (sourceDbLastModified.Date > lastModified.Date)
                            {
                                UpdateLocalMaxMindDb();
                            }
                        }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 _logger.InsertLog(LogLevel.Error, "Error." + e, string.Empty, null);
}

public void UpdateLocalMaxMindDb()
    {
        try
        {
            var destinationPath = _webhelper.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            string[] latestmmdb = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.mmdb");

            // Copy mmdb files.
            foreach (string f in latestmmdb)
            {
                // Remove path from the file name.
                string fName = f.Substring(sourcePath.Length + 1);
                string sourcefile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fName);
                string destinationfile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fName);

                int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(destinationfile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    fileStream.SetLength(fs.Length);
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

                    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(bytes, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();
                }

            }

        }

        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
        {
            _logger.InsertLog(LogLevel.Error, "Error." + dirNotFound, string.Empty, null);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Oldschool way to copy files with streams in 2k19?:) Take a look at [File.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I also tried File.copy().Problem occurs on production not on local.It works well on local.

Comment: `File.Copy` is not a solution for your problem. It is a solution for code quality. More then a half of your code sample can be safely replaced with just one line: `File.Copy(sourcefile, destinationfile);`

Comment: The account the process is running on has read/write permissions on both the source and target locations?

Comment: Also, it is **very** important to **read** exception messages. Which specific part of this: _"The process cannot access the file 'bla-bla-bla.mmdb' because it is being used by another process."_ you don't undersand?

Comment: Looking closer at the error message and your code, you are asking for read/write permissions on the source file when something else may have it open. Try read only.

Comment: This path 'D:\Websites\test\test.xyz.com\App_Data\GeoIP2-Country.mmdb'  is 'destinationfile'.